# URLEncoder mangling my JSON

Tags: java

I am trying to make a REST call from an Android app, and I seem to be having trouble getting the proper data to the server.  The node side of things is getting queries like the following:

```
            { '{"search_term":"eese"}': '' }
```

The sending code from the app is:

```
            OutputStream out = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            String body = r.getJSONString();
            String body_encoded = URLEncoder.encode(body, "UTF-8");
            out.write(body_encoded.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            out.close();
```

If I step through the above code, I see that body is

```
            "{"search_term":"eese"}"
```

And advice?

Comment: What are you using for sending?

Comment: Why are you URL encoding JSON?

Comment: URLEncoder (a) doesn't have the effect described and (b) shouldn't be used here in the first place.

Comment: @egh I'm using HttpURLConnection

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis this happens when I change the write to body.getBytes as well.  It was a suggestion I found somewhere

Comment: @EJP what exactly are you suggesting?

Comment: I'm not suggesting anything. I'm stating two facts. As your answer shows, a correct description of your problem would be 'Wrong content-type mangling my JSON'.

Comment: An advice. Use  volley

Answer (score 0):

It seems my issue arose from an incorrect Content-Type.

I added

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/JSON");
```

and the server started getting the correctly formatted items.

Comment: So URLEncoder had nothing to do with it, as I stated.